# Why is aggressive garbage collection in our Node.js app causing 100%+ CPU with plenty of memory to spare?

Tags: node.js, performance, garbage-collection, cpu-usage

We are trying to diagnose a performance regression after a major upgrade from Node v12 to v18 among some accompanying application code changes. During load testing, we observe the following changes (before in 1st picture, after in 2nd picture):

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kICwi.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Iex.png)

- CPU

  - before: 40%
  - after: 138%
- Garbage Collection Pause Count

  - before: 5gcs
  - after: 100gcs
- Garbage Collection Pause Time

  - before: 70ms
  - after: 270ms
- Event loop iterations per second

  - before: 350
  - after: 28
- Memory usage

  - [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcUhz.png): heap total is flat, heap used is a sawtooth wave with about a 30 second periodicity
  - [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNLaj.png): both heap total and heap used are flat

There does not appear to be a memory leak in either case, and there is about a full GB of memory left to spare, so what could be causing this spike in CPU/garbage collection? For context this is a very typical node, graphql server.

I would expect garbage collection and cpu to spike only if there is actual memory pressure.

Comment: I am also noticing the exact increase with v18.17.1. Has anyone found any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

We were setting `--optimize_for_size` per [Heroku's recommendations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#avoid-garbage), but this was ill-advised and should be strongly caveated in their docs.